# Какой выбрать предлог (под/на)?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, словосочетания

Поставить подпись под последним листом или на последнем листе?

Answer (score 1):

**Поставить подпись на последнем листе**

Поставить подпись под документом (текстом) - значит заверить его своей подписью. В остальных случаях "поставить подпись под чем-либо" указывает на  расположение подписи на листе (ниже упомянутого чего-либо), например, поставить подпись под последней строкой, под линией и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

Поставить подпись можно *под чем-либо*, и это будет фамилия (или подпись из паспорта, например), написанная собственноручно. Если же речь идет о любой надписи, то она может быть *под или на чем-либо*.

*(Использованы сведения из БТС.)*